# Returning an object from a function C++

Tags: c++, function, computer-science

Lets say I have a variable which points to an object I made. For this example, lets say I have an object that represents a card, which has 2 members - rank and suit.

Next, lets say I initialized that object structure I made, so I now have a card object with rank and suit.

My question is what if I want a function that returns this card object that I created:
I want to do something like this:

```
Card* playerCard = foo()
```

I know playerCard is pointing to a card object, so does this mean foo() has to return a card object as well? Is there another approach to this problem?

Basically I want my function to generate the card, and playerCard should be equal to the card that is generated. I don't know if returning an object is the most straightforward approach to the problem, that's why I'm also asking if there are any alternative solutions.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure of all of your requirements, but I think returning a `Card`, instead of a `Card*`, should do just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to progressively go from bad to good methods.

Firstly, this is the wrong way to do it:

```
Card* foo() {
  Card c;
  return &c;
}
```

Definitely don't do that. The `Card` `c` will be destroyed at the end of `foo` and so the pointer you return will be pointing at an invalid object.

You *could* do this:

```
Card* foo() {
  return new Card();
}
```

The card created by `new Card()` has dynamic storage duration, so it is not destroyed at the end of `foo`. Therefore the returned pointer is still pointing at that card. You can then use the pointer and be safe.

However, this has another downside. It's not clear to the person who calls `foo`, but they're now responsible for doing `delete` on the pointer that was returned to make sure there are no memory leaks. Instead, it is best to use a smart pointer to clearly pass ownership to the caller:

```
std::unique_ptr<Card> foo() {
  return std::unique_ptr<Card>(new Card());
}
```

However, even better is if you don't need dynamic allocation at all. Why not just return the `Card` and let it be copied out of the function? You can do it like so:

```
Card foo() {
  return Card();
}
```

Then instead of assigning to a pointer, you would call the function like so:

```
Card c = foo();
```

This, of course, depends on your requirements allowing this. If you want to use the `Card*` polymorphically, you'll need to use one of the pointer approaches. Otherwise you'll end up slicing your `Card` derivatives.

Comment: +1. You're unstoppable today ;)

Comment: "Why not just return the `Card`?"  Because you might want to inherit from `Card`, in which case you're in big danger of slicing.

Comment: @MattPhillips Sure, that's why I asked. :D

Comment: You did?  Drawing attention to the (recently developed) `unique_ptr` option is great, but for the perfect answer IMO you would put in explicit mention of the slicing danger of returning `Card`, esp. since there are lots of different cards out there, it's a likely polymorphism candidate.

Comment: Thank you very much - I ended up testing all the different implementations you suggested to see how they work. I would upvote if I had the reputation, but I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to an object there, not an object.

I'm not sure exactly what your problem here is so I'll just give you a full example:

```
struct card {int rank; int suit};

card make_a_card() {
   return card{10,3};
}

int main() {
    card a_card = make_a_card();
    // a_card == card{10,3}
}
```

You rarely want to return raw pointers from a function. It's not necessary for speed (in fact, thanks to RVO and move semantics it can actually end up being slower), so aside from runtime-polymorphism (i.e. for a factory method) there's little reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic memory allocation if you want to return a pointer, otherwise your pointer would point to nothing after the execution of `foo` (see [*Dangling pointers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)):

```
Card* foo() {
    Card* ret = new Card(...);
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

Another version of the above code would use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) from the standard library to make it clear to the client programmer of your code that you are returning a dynamic allocated pointer. It is a smart pointer therefore it will automatically deallocate itself at the end of its scope (which is not at the end of the function because it is copied to the calling block).

Otherwise if your object / struct is not expensive to copy you could return it by value leading to a copy being made:

```
Card foo() {
    Card ret(...);
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It is very likely that the copy will be elided in the second code sample, so expense of copying shouldn't be a consideration.

Comment: @juanchopanza, it really depends on the implementation of specific compilers, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does, but it would be hard to find one that doesn't do that these days.

Answer (score 0):

If the function foo() returns a pointer to a Card object that's already created, assigning a Card pointer to it should work just fine. It's important to remember that you're effectively passing it **the same card** though, not a copy or anything.